# How do I access a private variable in a public function that is overridden in the public function

Tags: javascript

For example

```
var MyClass = function(){

  var that = this;

  var my_var = "I want this";

  var another_var = "this one is easy";

  this.aPublicFunc = function(my_var){

    console.log(my_var);   // logs "I don't want this";
    console.log(another_var);  // logs "this one is easy";
    console.log(this.my_var);  // logs undefined which makes sense as the this context is the context of the calling function.
    console.log(that.my_var);  // logs undefined
  };
};

var an_object = new MyClass();
var an_object.aPublicFunc("I don't want this");
```

Comment: Why don't you just rename your second `my_var`?

Comment: The answer is: You don't. Name your variables and function arguments better.

Comment: `my_var` and `another_var` are global variables in your examples. Global variables and local variables are not magically becoming properties of the object you created, so `that.my_var` does not work unless you assign it explicitly. In your example, when calling `an_object.aPublicFunc(...)` `this` refers to `that` as well.

Comment: @deceze Because I'm curious to know if it is possible.

Comment: @Felix King. Ooops, corrected the global statements to be local.

Comment: @Felix King. If I assign that.my_var = my_var in the constructor then I can access it. But this makes it a public variable. Is there no way to do this and keep it private.

Comment: Not without renaming it. But I'm against this way of implementing encapsulation anyway. You end up creating a new `aPublicFunc` for each instance. Better is to use JSDoc and tag the corresponding properties as `@private` (unless it is security related).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private variables like you have with `my_var` are only accessible from code in the constructor and from the functions defined inside their scope (like in `aPublicFunc()`) when it is called.  And, to access them, you have to use a normal javascript reference to them.  When you define an argument to `aPublicFunc()` with the same name, you hide that outer scope variable and there is NO way to reach it as defined.  Those private variables are not members of the object, they are variables captured in a closure.  In javascript, the only way to reach variables in a closure is from code in the scope of that closure and you can only reach them if nothing has overridden their name.

Your simple solution is to change the name of the argument or the local variable to something slightly different.   If you really want them to look similar, then put an underscore in front of one of them like this:

```
var MyClass = function(){

  var that = this;
  var _my_var = "I want this";
  var _another_var = "this one is easy";

  this.aPublicFunc = function(my_var){

    console.log(_my_var);   // logs "I want this";
    console.log(_another_var);  // logs "this one is easy";
    console.log(my_var);  // logs "I don't want this"
  };
};

var an_object = new MyClass();
var an_object.aPublicFunc("I don't want this");
```

or make the argument a bit more obvious like this:

```
var MyClass = function(){

  var that = this;
  var my_var = "I want this";
  var another_var = "this one is easy";

  this.aPublicFunc = function(new_my_var){

    console.log(my_var);   // logs "I want this";
    console.log(another_var);  // logs "this one is easy";
    console.log(new_my_var);  // logs "I don't want this"
  };
};

var an_object = new MyClass();
var an_object.aPublicFunc("I don't want this");
```

You can see this last one work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Jeaaz/

Answer (score 2):

Don't override it. It makes the code less readable and more confusing.

Comment: In this case it is a setter. So it makes sense to have the same name. But I can't set it if I can't see it.

Comment: Even so, it's still confusing IMO. They do not represent the same thing, so it does make sense to call them the same thing. The parameter represents a new value/an input value, while the other my_var from the outer scope represents the old/current state of the object. Suppose you managed to read from the outside my_var, how would you know, looking at that line in isolation, whether you were reading the old/current state or the new/future state? It helps readability a lot if there is something in the name/reference that sets the two apart, e.g. newvalue, currentvalue, state.value etc.

Comment: In other languages you would use this.my_var = my_var, unfortunately here the only way to do that seems to be to make my_var public, which is what I am trying to avoid. It being private also avoids the problem with accessing it elsewhere.

Comment: You could go the `state.my_var` route, as in `var state = {my_var:'I want this', other_var:'something'};` and accessed by `state.my_var`. Very readable and clear (there's never any doubt whether a variable is part of the object state or not), but forces you to type `state.` all the time and it is essentially the same as just using a different name/prefix.